# How to clone an object and recursively set Id to Null?

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, java-stream, dozer

Here my use case :

I have 4 classes A,B,C,D

- class A contains an object ( type B ) and a list of objects ( type C )
- class B contains an object ( type D )

I want to clone the class A , and set the id to null recursively.

Here an example :

```
public class ClassA {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private boolean ok;
    private ClassB classB;
    private List<ClassC> classCList;

}
```

---

```
public class ClassB {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private ClassD classD;

}
```

---

```
public class ClassC{

    private Long id;
    private String name;

}
```

---

```
public class ClassD{

    private Long id;
    private String name;

}
```

---

I developed two functions to implement that :
**First method :**

```
public ClassA prepareClassA(ClassA detail) {

   Optional.ofNullable(detail).ifPresent( detail -> {
    detail.setId(null);
    Optional.ofNullable(detail).map(ClassA::getClassB)
            .ifPresent(objectB -> objectB.setId(null));

   Optional.ofNullable(detail).map(ClassA::getClassB).map(ClassB::getClassD)
            .ifPresent(objectB -> objectB.setId(null));

   Optional.ofNullable(detail).map(ClassA::getClassCList).
        .ifPresent(items -> items.stream().forEach(item -> {
            item.setId(null);
        }));

   }
}
```

**Second method** : ( included dozerMapper )

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
    <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And i used the DozerBeanMapper implementation

```
public ClassA prepareClassA(ClassA detail) {

    ClassA objectA = new ClassA();

    DozerBeanMapper dozerBeanMapper = new DozerBeanMapper();

    BeanMappingBuilder bean = beanMappingBuilder(ClassA.class);

    dozerBeanMapper.addMapping(bean);
    Optional.ofNullable(detail).ifPresent(detail -> dozerBeanMapper.map(detail, objectA));
    return details;
}


public BeanMappingBuilder beanMappingBuilder(Class<?> source) {
    return new BeanMappingBuilder() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            mapping(source, source,
                TypeMappingOptions .wildcard(true)
                //Here i have to do my work ?
                //TypeMappingOptions.mapNull(true)
            );
        }
    };
}
```

I want to have this result :

```
ClassA testA = new ClassA();
//fill all the objects in objectA with id != null

ClassA testA_convert = prepareClassA(testA);

// testA_convert.getId() must be null
// testA_convert.getClassB().getId() must be null
// testA_convert.getClassB().getClassD().getId() must be null
// testA_convert.getClassCList().forEach( element -> element.getId()  must be null
```

Questions :

- Is there any existing libary that can solve my problèm ?
- Can DozerMapper do that ?
- What is the best way to do that ?

Best regards

Comment: The error is already in the requirements.

Comment: Can you explain please ? which requirement are you talking about ?

Comment: The requirement to clone such an object graph and setting ids to `null`. Besides that, if such an operation is really required, add a method to these classes doing the operation.

Comment: @Holger See that : [github rep - deep cloning](https://github.com/ayoub62/deepcloning_reflection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that i found an easy way to do it :

implement Gson library :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
   <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

And add

```
public class ClassA {

   private Long id;

   @Expose
   private String name;

   @Expose
   private boolean ok;

   @Expose
   private ClassB classB;

   @Expose
   private List<ClassC> classCList;

}

public class ClassB {

   private Long id;

   @Expose
   private String name;

   @Expose
   private ClassD classD;

}
```

I put @Expose onto all fields != id

Here the implementation in my main class

```
    import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;

    public ClassA prepareClassA(ClassA detail) {

       Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
       ClassA object_A = gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(detail),ClassA.class);
       return  object_A;

    }
```

And it works .

**But** , is there a way to put @Expose only one time onto the class definition for all attributes ( excluding Id )

Example :

```
@Expose( exclude ="id" )
public class ClassB {

   private Long id;
   private String name;
   private ClassD classD;

}
```

Any Help ?

Answer (score 1):

if you already cloned your object and want to set id's to null without having a NPE, then you can create a helper interface for that:

```
interface Nullify<T> {
    void apply(T obj);

    default <G> Nullify<T> andThen(Function<T, G> function, Nullify<G> nullify) {
        return (T t) -> {
            apply(t);
            G g = function.apply(t);
            if(g != null) {
                nullify.apply(g);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

and the usage

```
Nullify<ClassB> bNull = b -> b.setId(null);
bNull = bNull.andThen(ClassB::getClassD, d -> d.setId(null));

Nullify<ClassA> aNull = a -> a.setId(null);
aNull.andThen(ClassA::getClassB, bNull)
     .andThen(ClassA::getClassCList, classCList -> classCList.forEach(c -> c.setId(null)))
     .apply(classAObject);
```

although it's better to configure clone/copy method to ignore ids (e.g. like MapStruct)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any existing library that can solve my problem ?

Yes, [MapStruct](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mapstruct/mapstruct) has the option to ignore the properties you want.

For example, define a configuration interface

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface DomainDtoMapper {

   @Mapping(source = "id", target = "id", ignore = true)
   ClassA map(ClassA cla);

   @Mapping(source = "id", target = "id", ignore = true)
   ClassB map(ClassB clb);

   //...
}
```

then just autowire `DomainDtoMapper` and call the method, it will check all your mapping rules and copy accordingly:

```
@Autowire DomainDtoMapper mapper;

//...

public ClassA prepareClassA(ClassA detail) {
    return mapper.map(detail);
}
```